# Convert .env file into params for Docker

Tags: awk, sed

I have a regular `.env`-file and wanna pass these (or some) vars to a Docker container like here:

.env file:

```
VAR1=blah
VAR2=some other blah
```

docker command:
`docker run myimage -e VAR1=blah -e VAR2=some other blah`

How can I achieve that with regular Unix commands like `awk` or `sed` (or similar)?

Comment: Why can't you directly use the `--env-file` option and pass the file directly?

Comment: @Inian: The only thing I can think of, which would make the use of `$ docker run my_image --env-file=my.env` difficult would be that `my.env` does not have the right `TAG=env_var_value\n` format with 1 tag per line.... But that (feeble) reason is disproved by the .env file shown in OP...

Answer (score 0):

try

```
awk -F= '{printf "%s=\"%s\" ",$1,$2 ;}' file.env
```

to generate var

docker command would be

```
docker run myimahe $(awk -F= '{printf "-e %s=\"%s\" ",$1,$2 ;}' file.env) other
```

note the `-e` in later case.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU `sed` you can let `sed` run the command with the `e` flag:

```
sed 's/^/-e /;H;1s/^/docker run myimage /;1h;$!d;x;s/\n/ /ge' your.env
```

This will collect the lines in the hold space with the `-e` option and the docker call and execute the whole command on the last line.